# Displayt comma seperated list of values in pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet with one column of keywords and a second column list of URLs/landing pages. The keywords are unique but the URLs are limited e.g.

Column 1:

- keyword1
- keyword2
- keyword3
- keyword7
- keywordabc
- keyworddef
- keywordxyz

Column 2:

- example.com/landingpage1
- example.com/landingpage2
- example.com/landingpage4
- example.com/landingpage1
- example.com/landingpage3
- example.com/landingpage1
- example.com/landingpage2

What I'm trying to achieve is a pivot table output that shows the landing page and its matching keywords so e.g.

```
example.com/landingpage1 | keyword1, keyword7, keywordabc, keywordxyz
example.com/landingpage2 | keyword2, keyword3, keyworddef
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you visually clarify the desired output? Maybe with a screenshot, or providing a copy of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 {A1:A&",", B1:B&"×"}, 
 "select max(Col1)
  where not Col1 starts with ',' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]